# About triangles in HTML, I saw solutions using borders, translate, etc, but no one solving this issue: how to set a link only to the triangle area?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, cursor, triangle

I want to create a triangle and set a link (changing cursor etc) only to the visible area of this triangle, leaving the transparent area untouched and unlinked.

All the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work), I tried to modify but the cursor and the link were in all the rectangle area, not only in the visible triangle.
Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: it seems you didn't check *all* the solutions there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896783/8620333

Comment: This is not true. If you try to add a link to the triangle made using any of those answers, the link will be on the square and not only on the triangle.

Comment: I didn't edit my answer. No need to be rude and better see the changes I made to the answer that is not mine. I simply removed an outdated part that is no more needed as the answer is from 2016.

Comment: So... If you "just removed outdated part", means you edited the answer. The way it was, didn't work. Instead of reduce my reputation, setting my question as duplicated, why don't you simple answered it here!? Who is being rude?

Comment: *The way it was, didn't work.* --> It did work, removing the outdated part will not change how the code works. Test both codes before claiming wrong things. Closing question as duplicate is a website feature. It's not a punishment or being rude.

Comment: and don't edit your question to add irrelevant content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a clip path

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

div:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```